# How to get the exact color as output that we are looking for?

Tags: color-management

I have been learning Blender recently. And I have understood that lighting plays an important role in getting the exact shade of color that we want. But I am still not clear on how to achieve this.

For ex, I am trying to create a plane for my background with the color(Hex: #ffc1c2). But no matter how much I play with the lighting(Area and point)I am unable to get this color as output in the rendered image using cycles.

Can anyone help me on how to get the color that we want as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values and position of your lights (and world/HDRI) will affect the color of your object, and all the indirect lights as well, so you can't get the exact same color, except, of course, if you use an *Emission* node.

I've noticed though that if you delete all source of light, create a sun, reset its rotation, give it a *Strength* of 3.1 and an *Angle* of 0, you'll get the exact same color in render. So if you want to keep the exact same color you need to stay around these values, or if you play with one of these values you need to compensate with another.

If you test *Emission* or a sun with this precise setup but still don't get the exact same color, it may have to do with the *Render* settings (example: the *Color Management* settings, *View Transform* must be on *Standard*).

Comment: Thank you. It was the view transform. Playing around with raw and standard did it.

Comment: Except this is the worst possible solution for rendering light transport. Your dynamic range is extremely thin, and the mixtures will all skew as the three light mixture cannot be represented in the display output. Don’t do this.

Comment: Hello Troy, are you talking about the Standard option?

Comment: Using Hex to understand color in blender is not a good place to start. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43503/92768 Blender works with a [**scene referred radiometrically linear reference space mode**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23220/92768) more info on these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35722/when-to-use-srgb-and-when-not-to/35854#35854 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender

Comment: and, of course this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im/46940#46940